# 550: Header Reply-to: exists, but verify failed due to route; xxxx@xxxx.com

Tags: email, sendgrid

I've got a site that sends out emails via the sendgrid smtp service. It generally has run without too many issues but recently we had emails sent out that gave the error

```
550: Header Reply-to: exists, but verify failed due to route; xxxx@xxxx.com
```

I've tried searching on Google and SO and I can see plenty of 550 errors around but none with this specific message. Is it purely down to the 'reply-to' email being invalid in someway - is there a way I can avoid the error aside from making 100% sure any reply-to address set are completely legit?

Many thanks for any solutions or information.

Comment: Would you have been seeing this error while trying to send mail to the Netregistry MX?